# Fetch data from mysql by checking radio button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have few models of products and when i click on each model to show me his variants, like on image from below

[image: i]

Here is what i made in html :

```
     <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme no-pb slide-arrow-2" data- 
        dots="false" data-nav="true" data-items="4" data-lg-items="3" 
         data-md-items="2" data-sm-items="2" data-margin="30" data- 
         autoplay="false">
            <?php 
              $qua = "SELECT * FROM produse WHERE categorie = '$id' ORDER BY pozitie";
              $qla = mysqli_query($conn, $qua);
              while($rova = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qla)){?> 
                <?php 
                    $id_paletar = $rova['id'];
                    $sql2=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM pret_produse WHERE produs_id='$id_paletar'");
                    $pret2=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
                 ?>
               <div class="item">
                  <div class="product-item">
                     <div class="product-img">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="cms/produse/<?=$rova['poza'];?>" alt="">
                        <div class="product-overlay">
                           <ul class="list-unstyled">
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="product-btn ifix">
                        <div class="btn btn-theme btn-block btn-new" ><span style="font-size: 15px;"><?=$rova['titlu'];?></span>
                            <div>
                            <label class="containere">
                              <input type="radio" name="produse" id="paletar_pret" class="palt" value="<?=$rova['id'];?>">
                              <p class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            <?php }?>
        </div>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.palt').change(function() {
      if(this.checked) {
        var check= $(this).val();
        alert(check);
          $.ajax({
                url: 'cere_cotatie.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {check:check},
                success: function(data){
                    $('.fetch').append(data);
                }
            });
      }
  });
```

And here is my php file which i use on ajax to call:

```
  <?php
  if($_POST)
 {
       include('config.php');

   echo $check = $_POST['check'];
   $s = "SELECT * FROM variante WHERE id_var='$check'"; 
   $q = mysqli_query($conn, $s);
   while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {?>
     <div class="item" style="width:220px;">
          <div class="product-item">
             <div class="product-img">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="cms/variante/<?=$r['poza'];?>" alt="">
                <div class="product-overlay">
                   <ul class="list-unstyled">
                   </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="product-btn ifix">
                <div class="btn btn-theme btn-block btn-new" ><span style="font-size: 15px;"> <?=$r['denumire'];?></span>  
                  <div>
                        <label class="containere">
                          <input type="checkbox">
                          <p class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                  </div>

                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
  <?php }?>

   <?php }
  ?>
```

My problem is like this if i check first box to display me variants of what i checked but my code is doing this way, if i check first box is loading data and after that if i check another box results from first box need to dissapear and to be only what i check.
EDIT: in that print screen you can see the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add below code

```
$('.palt').change(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

and remove `alert(check);`

Hope it work for you.

Comment: I put what you give to me and he is doing the same thing

Comment: Why do you "think you should add below code"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.